# Join rows in a spark dataframes by key?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have a data frame that has two columns one for user and the second is for their post. I want to create a another dataframe that is the username and all of their posts.

example of what I have

```
username   post

--------   ----

Bob        I want the new Iphone7

Alice      Anyone else buying the google pixel 

Bob        Just bought a mac book pro
```

What I want is

```
Username  Post

bob      I want new Iphone7 Just bought a mac book pro

Alice    Anyone else buying the google pixel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would groupBy(username) and then use concat_ws(post) using single space as your character to concatenate your Post column. Please refer this official pyspark documentation:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws